# Loop over keys in a child object and display both key and value

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I am using react. I have data I am getting from my API in the form of JSON(already converted to object). The object -

```
{
    _id: '1',
    specs: {
        chip: 'H1-based',
        connectivity: 'Bluetooth 5.0',
    },
}
```

I want to display the key value pairs(on the website, this is NOT an object)

```
Chip: H1-based
Connectivity: Bluetooth 5.0
```

This is the place where I want to add the necessary logic in my code -

```
<ListGroup.Item className="product__detail-row">
    The entire object shown above is in a variable called product.
</ListGroup.Item>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put text in your JSX by using a JSX expression, which looks like `{valueHere}`. You can get the entries of an object as `[key, value]` pairs via the `Object.entries` function, then map them to JSX elements via `map`. So applying that to your situation:

```
<ListGroup.Item className="product__detail-row">
{Object.entries(product.specs).map(([key, value]) =>
    <div>{initialCap(key)}: {value}</div>
)}
</ListGroup.Item>
```

In that example I wrapped the display of each key/value pair in a `div`, but you can use whatever suits your situation.

I've used a hypothetical function `initialCap` there to convert your property names, which are in all lower case, to initially-capitalized strings. FWIW, a simple version of that function might be:

```
function initialCap(str) {
    return str.charAt(0).toLocaleUpperCase() + str.substring(1);
}
```

...though since JavaScript characters are effectively UTF-16 code units and sometimes it takes a pair of code units to make a "character," a more general version might work in code *points* instead of code *units*:

```
function initialCap(str) {
    const [first] = str; // Spread and destructuring work by code _points_, not code units
    return first.toLocaleUpperCase() + str.substring(first.length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[ToolJS](https://github.com/REDEAKAA/ToolJS) has an "Obj" module that holds a method which loops through an object, firing a callback for each property pair, outputting the properties key and value to the callbacks arguments for each property.

Get the library either through [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@redeakaa/tooljs) or [CDN](https://unpkg.com/@redeakaa/tooljs@1.0.1/dist/umd/tooljs.min.js)

```
// require the Obj module from the package
const { Obj } = require("@redakaa/tooljs");

// use the .forEach method available to the Obj module
Obj.forEach(myObj, function(key, value){
    console.log(`Current key: ${key}, Current value: ${value}`);
});
```

Check out the libraries full docs [here](https://redeakaa.github.io/ToolJS/)

> Ref: [ToolJS Object Manipulation](https://redeakaa.github.io/ToolJS/module-Obj.html)